# Classifying Sentences when outcome is a sentence

Tags: classification, natural-language, language-models

I am completely new to text classification and facing the following problem, I want to classify sentences and have a labeled dataset, the thing is that my Y variable is itself a sentence, hence I wanted to ask what is the best approach to follow here.

I could relabel my Y as 1, 2, 3 and then apply some kind of multinomial regression or something like this. It seems to me that in this way I am loosing some information. Maybe somebody have a suggestion on how to proceed in this case

Comment: Could you give an example of your data inputs and desired outputs? How complex are the output sentences?

Comment: @Alex R. For example: Y_1 = "Tomatos 5kg, two deliveries", Y_2 = "Tomatos 6kg, three deliveries", X_1 = "This package contains 5kg of tomatos, which will be delivered in 2 deliveries", X_2 = "This package contains 6kg of tomatos, which will be delivered in 3 deliveries"

Comment: This is not classification.

Comment: @A. M. Bittlingmayer, this is a very good comment maybe you can suggest some help ?

Comment: @Vitalijs sequence output, sequence to sequence, seq2seq